# how to pass a value to Odata connector

Tags: parameter-passing, odata, key-value, visual-studio-lightswitch, connector

I am trying to pass a value to my O data Connector that I build in VS 2013, so that it should return results based on that value (a number value from a table that i have).could you tell me some steps to resolve this?

Comment: Show us the code that you've tried and where, _specifically_, you're having trouble.

Comment: Actually, I donno where to start. But what I have is, Odata connector with couple of tables (.isml extensions). I need to find out how to pass a value and how to get results based on that value?Any tutorial or steps how to start this?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following article on MDSN to be of use:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx

A more comprehensive set of documentation on OData URL conventions can be found over here: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions **Note:** This is assuming that your OData connection is being instantiated via URL inside HTML Client javascript code.

If you are using an external application, simply install the Microsoft.OData.Client binary using NuGet and you can just write linq queries against the connection.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933(v=vs.110).aspx for additional information about this pattern.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay I can try that.I have one more question. I have a ODATA Connector and a seperate light switch application which uses this Odata Connector. I need to set up permission on Odata connector ( like read and edit) so that it should reflect on my light switch app. any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm... I've only done that sort of thing backwards - i.e. calling the LightSwitch authentication model from an external app to setup new accounts, etc.  There's a service reference you can include (Microsoft.LightSwitch.SecurityData.svc in the root folder of your LS app) that will provide an OData interface to the LightSwitch security model.  Not sure if you can secure resources outside of LightSwitch using that.